# Can I pass commandline arguments when invoking "zig build run"?

Tags: command-line-arguments, zig

I'm just starting with the new programming language Zig and finding documentation pretty sparse.

I can build and run the current project by invoking `zig build run`.

I can also do `zig run src/main.zig` assuming standard project layout.

But in neither case can I find a way to pass along commandline arguments to my project.

I know that after building I can invoke my project as a binary as `zig-out/bin/<my project's name> foo bar` but is there a way to do it straight from `build run`?

Just trying the obvious `zig build run foo bar` tells me `Cannot run step 'foo' because it does not exist`.

None of the commandline switches for zig itself seem to do what I want and I can't find anyone discussing this by Googling for it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

just pass your arguments after `--` (`zig build run -- <args>`)
e.g:

```bash
zig build run -- foo bar
```

Comment: Thanks! I don't use *nix commandlines regularly enough for me to immediately recall that standard feature. It could benefit from being in the help assuming I'm not the only one.

Comment: Looks like this doesn't work on Windows.

Comment: Whoops, it does work.  You just need to use `run_step.addArgs()` like in https://zig.news/xq/zig-build-explained-part-1-59lf